# Wordpress autentication from another applications

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, authentication

I have a stable PHP system running with tons of data from my users. to help on support and sales of this system, we are developing a WordPress application, on multisite mode, that will contain Wiki, blog, Helpdesk and other features. as you can see, it would be really cool if the users who are already signed on my system could use the same login/pass to log in the WordPress application.

Any of you did something like this before?
I have the structure to make a webserver well formed, but don't see where on wordpress I could override the default behavior to make this possible.
The applications are, of course, on different servers.

Comment: Wordpress allows you to customize authentication by plugging into the "authenticate" filter. There are several tutorials on the net that show you how.